# Kafka Error vs Error Field within each TopicPartition in the confluent kafka python on_commit callback()

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, librdkafka

I'm writing a kafka consumer using confluent-kafka in Python. I'm using the async*commit API. The documentation for the on*_commit callback says the following. I don't understand the different between the First error argument and the individual errors within each TopicPartition argument. Can someone show me an example of how to handle this callback?

- `on_commit(kafka.KafkaError, list(kafka.TopicPartition))` (**Consumer**): Callback used to indicate success or failure of asynchronous and automatic commit requests. This callback is served upon calling `consumer.poll()`. Is not triggered for synchronous commits. Callback arguments: *KafkaError* is the commit error, or None on success. *list(TopicPartition)* is the list of partitions with their committed offsets or per-partition errors.

What would the arguments look like if
- there was no error
- there were some errors
- all of them errored out

Answer (score 0):

> there was no error

First param would be `None`, as well as all TopicPartition.error

> there were some errors

Some `TopicPartition.error` would be `None`. Everything else would not.

> all of them errored out

All errors would be not None